# Sync method chaining in Typescript w/o promises/generics to return caller?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following example:

```
const sdk = new MySDK();
sdk
  .foo('foo1').done<MySDK>() // ideally .done() returns instance of MySDK w/o T
  .foo('foo2')
    .bar('bar1').done<Foo>() // ideally .done() returns instance of Foo w/o T
    .baz('baz1').done<Foo>() // ideally .done() returns instance of Foo w/o T
    .done<MySDK>() // ideally .done() returns instance of MySDK w/o T
  .finalize();
```

Is there a way to achieve sync method chaining in Typescript at compile-time without needing to specify the type (but still get method auto-completion in VS Code etc.)? Ideally this would look like:

```
sdk
  .foo('foo1').done()
  .foo('foo2')
    .bar('bar1').done()
    .baz('baz1').done()
    .done()
  .finalize();
```

Currently I am manually telling the compiler what the `done` method returns at compile-time and using state stored at runtime to determine the caller. The full source:

```
abstract class Creatable {
  creatableStack: MyObectType[];
  name: string;

  constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string) {
    console.log(creatableStack, name);

    this.creatableStack = creatableStack;
    this.name = name;

    this.creatableStack.push(this);
  }

  done<T>(): T {
    console.log('done', this.creatableStack);

    this.creatableStack.pop();

    const previousMyObject = this.creatableStack.at(-1);

    return previousMyObject as T;
  }

  bar(name: string): Bar {
    return new Bar(this.creatableStack, name);
  }
}

type MyObectType = MySDK | Foo | Bar | Baz;

class Bar extends Creatable {
  constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string) {
    super(creatableStack, name);
  }
}

class Foo extends Creatable {
  constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string) {
    super(creatableStack, name);
  }

  baz(name: string) {
    return new Baz(this.creatableStack, name);
  }
}

class Baz extends Creatable {
  constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string) {
    super(creatableStack, name);
  }
}

class MySDK {
  creatableStack: MyObectType[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.creatableStack.push(this);
  }

  foo(name: string): Foo {
    return new Foo(this.creatableStack, name);
  }

  finalize(): MySDK { 
    console.log('finalize', this.creatableStack);

    return this; 
  }
}

const sdk = new MySDK();
sdk
  .foo('foo1').done<MySDK>() // ideally .done() returns instance of MySDK w/o T
  .foo('foo2')
    .bar('bar1').done<Foo>() // ideally .done() returns instance of Foo w/o T
    .baz('baz1').done<Foo>() // ideally .done() returns instance of Foo w/o T
    .done<MySDK>() // ideally .done() returns instance of MySDK w/o T
  .finalize();
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this; there seem to be quite a few fiddly bits around which type of object is on the top of the stack when, and in order for this to possibly work you'd need all these classes to be generic in the state of the stack.  Could you pare it down to fewer classes with fewer weird dependencies? I think once you start naming things XYZZY you have probably gone too far (although I've certainly named things `qux` and `quux` in my day so ‍♂️)

Comment: I was able to remove XYZZY, but not sure how to pair it down further w/o losing the parent/child state for reference.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq3MRw) meet your needs?  Each type holds onto the type of the next item below it on the stack; if that works for you I could write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?  (Please comment @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: That is some generic magic! It does work :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, all of your classes need to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a type that encodes the current state of the stack.  One general approach is something like

```
declare class S<T = undefined> {
    push(): S<this>;
    pop(): T;
}
```

where the type parameter `T` is the type of the stack before you got here.  So when you call `push()`, you return `S<this>` using the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to show that you are returning a stack with `this` on top, and when you call `pop()` you return `T`, which is whatever the stack was when you started.

And you'd use it like this:

```
const s0 = new S(); 
// const s0: S<undefined>
const s1 = s0.push();
// const s1: S<S<undefined>>;
const s2 = s1.push();
// const s2: S<S<S<undefined>>>
const s3 = s2.pop();
// const s3: S<S<undefined>>
const s4 = s3.pop();
// const s4: S<undefined>
const s5 = s4.pop();
// const s5: undefined
```

You can see that the stack goes from `S` to `S<S>` to `S<S<S>>` and back to `S<S>`, `S`, and eventually `undefined`.

---

Adapting your class hierarchy is mostly about adding type parameters everywhere:

```
declare abstract class Creatable<T> {
    creatableStack: MyObectType[];
    name: string;
    constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string);
    done(): T; // <-- this is popping T off the stack
    bar(name: string): Bar<this>; // <-- this is pushing a Bar on the stack
}
declare class Bar<T> extends Creatable<T> {
    constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string);
}
declare class Foo<T> extends Creatable<T> {
    constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string);
    baz(name: string): Baz<this>; // <-- this is pushing a Baz on the stack
}
declare class Baz<T> extends Creatable<T> {
    constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string);
}
declare class XYZZY<T> extends Creatable<T> {
    constructor(creatableStack: MyObectType[], name: string);
}
declare class MySDK<T = undefined> { // default to an empty stack
    creatableStack: MyObectType[];
    constructor();
    foo(name: string): Foo<this>; // <-- this is pushing a Foo on the stack
    xyzzy(name: string): XYZZY<this>; // <-- this is pushing a XYZZY
    finalize(): MySDK; // <-- this essentially clears the stack
}
```

And we can test that it works as desired:

```
const sdk = new MySDK();
sdk // MySDK
    .foo('foo1') // Foo<MySDK>
    .done() // MySDK
    .foo('foo2') // Foo<MySDK>
    .bar('bar1') // Bar<Foo<MySDK>
    .done() // Foo<MySDK>
    .baz('baz1') // Baz<Foo<MySDK>>
    .done() // Foo<MySDK>
    .done() // MySDK
    .xyzzy('xyzzy') // XYZZY<MySDK>
    .bar('bar2') // Bar<XYZZY<MySDK>>
    .done() // XYZZY<MySDK>
    .done() // MySDK
    .finalize(); // MySDK
```

Looks good.  The stack seems to be in the correct state the whole way through.

---

Caveats here: I didn't bother keeping track of your original `ObjectType`; I just redefined it to `any`. It's possible you could make these properly generic in some way, but I don't know that it matters. If it does, it's probably out of scope for this question, which I interpret more about keeping track of state.

Also, your implementations are moving array references around and `push()`ing and `pop()`ping items onto and off of them.  That has the potential to be a problem. The types are immutable but the values are not, so if someone writes

```
sdk.foo('abc');
sdk.foo('def');
```

now you have two `Foo`s on the stack but that information is not properly encoded anywhere.  You have to try to enforce that you *only* chain method calls and that any references are used at most once, so that once you call `sdk.foo('abc')`, `sdk` is off-limits.  If you can't guarantee that, then you might want to make your values immutable also, by copying array contents instead of array references.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABNGBnViDKAeAKogXkQFcA7cAMwEtSwQA+RAb2ETcQAdjUALACgCUALizYALjyqp6AblbsOAew6CRuOQF9gERaVRjEqAAyFEtAO5ZBcgPQ3ku-YaMicZSjTr1tjg6gCMpsYAdFy81sB2Dnp+-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-Xm7u9x3+MQaBb6bYdfp93gfBzaU7VIBFhEQAAheBxGLWkw3YK8bzvCwIP-fcYzLQ8OSDa0a3YLQ620WAiUguAaUQMAAA8xDAcgMFJdCdTIttFV8FU1Q1EcUwDLln15V4LTzG0ZRAh1mOdVBiEuDiD1TbCQy-RB8JOQkMAAMUURQyMo6jaJJA8mKdJU2LEdUfQYrj9R4nkTX4wU5KE4DQMdCcJKkszk1nLDBNw78Tl-GAAC8AOtID4REkRIIC6CpFgicENvMwwEsSK+DQjzMMDbyFKUwi0AwSKtKomiQDo-TcFi9gjNVEzpPMzyDSNPiBTswTQvtZzC1csBavS2SsqdHKVMQAANABNAAtcbRsKnSSr0urqXKjqWJiYzTM4+qrONZ5bPstqROW8TJO69yML6nMfMU4A6yGm5MAAEQAaTwUwjlqQ6NoyramrNQVTCFAtKtY6rTNEuCiykacFtTSt+GrbK-PYCgNOCyV9tAkR1M0iMKsvMBrwS5CsdSqdPvOnCEadCizgCgKzlRhywoxkaJqm6LpEO+l4qQpKWcm0aSchsmA3sy6fyRmhQSoAKmzAu6ns5oG9E7btvQBFIpZlwdJyFmSx0BvGCbvCMEZu+ZUBAdlTGQ+XHoiC2raiW2nWCZHFF7N3-ABB0oix7Bbe8elgn7WXvnsZ2g7dj2NKyb2w8QP2A5dv8NQBFOvZ9+wSOwROzgex7A-YYPG0EePc-zwu2GCP8grTwKM-jgry6e+og5D0vfY0-285bl328zw0e8el3qdp+mAVHum46iMb+e7ivk--Ou4Fjgfs9ntmA8rxBi9oDv7A36ak7bkuB4jouNagaXZZkePbaAA)